# Inserting image, text and link in the object_story_spec, the post is created automatically and made visible on the fan page?

Tags: facebook-ads-api, fan-page

Good day.

I should want to create a POST_ENGAGEMENT Facebook Ad campaign creating a post on a fan page when I publish the adcreative. In order to develop it, now I use sandbox account. If I insert image, text and link on object_story_spec field, the post is automatically create and made visible on a fan page? Now I'm developing the source code of my web application with sandbox account and in this way I don't see the post on the specified fun page. If I use the real ad account the post is created on a page?

Best regards.

Stefano ERrani